# How to search Index of Substring in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to search `tenantDomain org_id` as mentioned in the below example string in a batch file.

```
<ax2697:tenantDomain>org_12345678
```

`ax2697` is always dynamic and i need to retrieve string `org_12345678` in batch file.

2 opertaions might be needed.

1. get index of "tenantDomain>"
2. retrieve org_12345678 from index.

I do not see any promising solution on forums.
Please suggest.

Comment: I don't see any promising attempts in your question either! This site isn't here to code it for you because you couldn't find one already written exactly how you want it. Here you provide the code you've written which exhibits a specific issue, and we try to help you fix it.

Comment: I do not see any command in findstr or find to retreive org_12345678 from this string <ax2697:tenantDomain>org_12345678

Comment: That is because `findstr` and `find` _commands_ are not designed to _retrieve substrings_, but to _find lines in files_. You may enter `findstr /?` or `find /?` and read the description of what the command does in the very first line...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid your question is pretty confusing... Do you need the *Index of Substring* or do you need *to retrieve a Substring*? Would you accept a solution that extracts a Substring without use its Index? **`:/`**

The Batch file below retrieve the substring placed *after* `tenantDomain>` in a larger string:

```
@echo off

set "string=<ax2697:tenantDomain>org_12345678"

set "x=%string:tenantDomain>=" & set "substring=%"

echo %substring%
```

Output:

```
org_12345678
```

Comment: Actually i am parsing this xml(allTenantsList.xml) which is written in 1 line only to get org_12345678. sample xml allTenantsList.xml in 1 line and contanis these 4 org_id tags.

Comment: <ax2697:tenantDomain>org_69449408</ax2697:tenantDomain>
<ax2697:tenantDomain>org_91450217</ax2697:tenantDomain>
<ax2697:tenantDomain>org_22118163</ax2697:tenantDomain>
<ax2697:tenantDomain>org_29724704</ax2697:tenantDomain>

Comment: so in the below script first i am formatting the XML line by line and when org_id tag is encountered i try to print it.But on 1st and 2nd iteration it is not printed but in 3rd and 4th print it bring values of 1st and 2nd org_id tags.

Comment: @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a variable with spaces
SET spaces= 
for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do SET "spaces=!spaces!!spaces!"

rem Read the line
for /F "delims=" %%a in (***allTenantsList.xml***) do SET "line=%%a"

SET level=0
:nextTag
   rem Separate first tag from line
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=<" %%a in ("!line!") do (
      SET "tag=%%a"
      SET "line=%%b"
   )
   rem Show first tag in one separate line
   if "%tag:~0,1%" equ "/" SET /A level-=5


SET searchVal="tenantDomain>"

set str1="!spaces:~0,%level%!^<!tag!"

Comment: if not x%str1:tenantDomain>=%==x%str1% (

if not x%str1:</=%==x%str1% (
rem echo It contains End tag
) else (
echo ORG Found 
echo printing New ORG tag
echo "%tag%"
set "string=%tag%"
set "x=%string:tenantDomain>=" & set "substring=%"
echo.%substring%
)
)

if "%tag:~0,1%" neq "/" SET /A level+=5
if defined line goto nextTag

Comment: This is the sample output of the above script.

ORG Found
printing New ORG tag
"ax2697:tenantDomain>org_69449408"

ORG Found
printing New ORG tag
"ax2697:tenantDomain>org_91450217"

ORG Found
printing New ORG tag
"ax2697:tenantDomain>org_22118163"
org_69449408
ORG Found
printing New ORG tag
"ax2697:tenantDomain>org_29724704"
org_91450217


Can you please look and suggest why org_id is not retreived on 1st and 2nd iteration.

What is the defect in this code.Is it something due to delayexecution?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set "string=<ax2697:tenantDomain>org_12345678"
set "string=%string:<=#%"
set "string=%string:>=#%"

set "find_index_of=org_12345678"

call :indexof "%string%" "%find_index_of%" index

echo %index%

exit /b 0
:indexof [%1 - string ; %2 - find index of ; %3 - if defined will store the result in variable with same name]
::http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1687
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "str=%~1"
set "s=!str:%~2=&rem.!"
set s=#%s%

if "%s%" equ "#%~1" endlocal& if "%~3" neq "" (set %~3=-1&exit /b 0) else (echo -1&exit /b 0) 

  set "len=0"
  for %%N in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%N,1!" neq "" (
      set /a "len+=%%N"
      set "s=!s:~%%N!"
    )
  )
  endlocal&if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%len%) else echo %len%
exit /b 0
```